# launch a cmd window with changed color and execute a jar file from a batchfile

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a *.bat file which runs a jar file and shows the console using 'cmd.exe'. 
But I want it in matrix like theme i.e. Black Background with green text.
But I am unable to create this. I tried few options most does not work, those which works starts cmd prompt in a infinite loop keep on creating cmd windows.

This is the initial file.bat which works fine with default colors.

```
 start java -jar MainMenu.jar 
 exit
```

This is one which changes the colors but keep on creating cmd windows

```
start /B cmd /k "COLOR 0A&&java -jar MainMenu.jar"
exit
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: What are MainMenu.jar and launcher.jar ?

Comment: also tried creating two files. A.bat and B.bat where A.bat changes color and runs B.bat using "call B.bat "

Comment: @SergeBallesta ohh sorry both are same file. Corrected

Comment: I cannot understand how you have a loop creating cmd windows. I tried with no problems (but without your MainMenu.jar ...). What does MainMenu.jar ?

Comment: that runs a java program which outputs to console

Comment: For me when I put `start cmd /k "color 0A && java -jar app.jar` in a batch file, and starts the bat either by double click in explorer or directly from a command prompt it opens one single cmd windows, green on black, display the outpu of app.jar and wait at command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Worked on my machine, i just had to add a `pause` to see the effects:

```
color 0a
java -jar launcher.jar
pause
```

Comment: I tried this also. As you can see I am using start cause I also trying change the title of the opened cmd window. Using 'title <string>' displays as Administrator:<string> not <string>.
But using start I can do a clear title, using start <string>.

Comment: you can also "title" your batch file using `title My Awesome Batch File`

Comment: @Alex using two batch files solved the issue. Regarding the 'Administrator:Name' the Administrator string can't be removed without  registry edit, which I don't want. It is there to show that the cmd window has elevated priviledges